# Usercard no longer expands while mousing over it

Tags: support, profile-page, users

I'm sure at some point we've all noticed while mousing over certain users picture/gravatar that extended information pops open about that person. Mine used to do this, although no longer seems to — just curious why it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 3):

For the user-info card to be expanded on hover you need more than 1000 rep, and a somewhat meaningful **about me** excerpt (more than 50 chars of text). Your about me isn't being recognized as such, so no hover card for you.

Comment: Hmm - was this a temporary bug? I'm seeing user cards when I roll over users with 1k on main sites. Is this a new change on child metas or dig child metas have no user cards in the first place?

Comment: I totally misunderstood the first question, due to the context of things that were happening at that time. I've updated my answers, as this has nothing to do with the top bar. To further elaborate, the user info hover cards feature is behind a site setting that can be turned off for each  individual site, but is currently enabled on all sites, so it should work as long as the criteria mentioned above are fulfilled.